# Unable to launch Firefox browser using selenium web driver

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to launch Firefox browser using selenium webdriver 3.4.0

Browser version: Firefox 54.0.1

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\xx\\geckodriver.exe");
     WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");
    driver.quit();
 }
}
```

Getting Error

> 1508548441651 geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.18.0
>   1508548441660 geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:48046 Exception
>   in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
>   localhost:48046 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]
>   failed: Connection refused: connect Build info: version: '3.4.0',
>   revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' System info: host:
>   'ADMINRG-627BJ6K', ip: '192.168.1.3', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch:
>   'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131' Driver info:
>   driver.version: FirefoxDriver     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:91)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:191)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:108)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:104)
>     at com.webdriver.Testing.main(Testing.java:15) Caused by:
>   org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
>   localhost:48046 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]
>   failed: Connection refused: connect   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:159)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:139)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:87)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:343)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:159)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
>     ... 8 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:
>   connect   at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native
>   Method)   at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
>   ... 23 more

Comment: Why have you added this statement: `System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe")` ?

Comment: I got advised from other friend. so that i added.

Comment: Any suggestions. because  still  i am facing  this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using driver of specific browser, you can use "Webdrivermanager" plugin in maven, so it will resolve most of problems related to browser and its instance. Even this help me lot to overcome browser related problems. E.g.
1. Add Webdrivermanager plugin with maven
2. Directly call browser of your choice like firefox as mentioned below.

FirefoxDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
driver= new FirefoxDriver();

Answer (score 2):

In case of some firefox browser version, driver is not able to launch browser using property "webdriver.gecko.driver". Instead of this you can try following code:

```
 DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way: I am using C#, but this way worked for me. You can follow same way of doing in Java
Provide 'firefox.exe' & 'GeckoDriver' as your local path

```
var binary = new FirefoxBinary(@"----Firefox.exe Path------");
var profile = new FirefoxProfile();
FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"----GeckoDriver Path------");
service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"----Firefox.exe Path------";
driverInstance = new FirefoxDriver(service);
```